# Unknown motor with continuity across all windings. Help identify star vs. delta

Tags: induction-motor, vfd, cnc

I'm converting an old milling machine (Optimum F40E) machine to be driven with a VFD, and I have it working. The head is a geared head, and with correct settings (torque compensation) in the VFD I can overcome the startup torque in the gear-train when the machine is shifted into the "high speed" gear.

**There is continuity between all six terminals in the terminal box on the motor.**

I measured the resistance between U/V/W 1..6 and found something unexpected. The housing for the wiring doesn't contain any bus-bars, so the motor must be internally wound a specific way.

Here's the motor info plate:

[image]

The resistance between the terminals is as such (I measured every terminal combination explicitly, even though this is redundant)

[image]

**Is this a star, or delta internal configuration, or is the motor damaged?**

Comment: I think there's an error in your second column at the bottom.

Comment: there is an error in "the row terminal designations" (the last one, by the looks of it), and I don't believe the value column #6, row #4 value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 'Dahlander' two-speed, pole-changing motor.

[image]

The windings are 'delta-connected' for 1400 RPM and 'double star-connected' for 2800  RPM.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing it out, greybeard. Was burning the midnight oil and uploaded the wrong version of the drawing!